# How to get uuid(dynamic value) in FeatureContext method

Tags: php, testing, bdd, behat, symfony-2.8

My code access only hard coded ID (/api/user/{id}). But I want it works with dynamic value (for example: uuid).

```
/**
 * @When I send a :http request to :url
 *
 * @param $http
 * @param $url
 */
public function iSendARequestTo($http, $url)
{
    $url = $this->attachQueries($url);

    if ($this->isUrlContainsRuntimeParameters($url)) {
        $url = $this->mergeRuntimeParametersValues($url);
    }

        $this->client->request(
            $http,
            $url,
            $this->parameters,
            [],
            $this->headers,
            $this->rawData
        );

    $this->response = $this->client->getResponse();
}
```

Extra Functions:

```
 private function attachQueries($url)
{
    foreach ($this->queries as $key => $value) {
        if(strpos($url,'?') !== false) {
            $url .= '&' .$key. '=' .$value;
        } else {
            $url .= '?' .$key. '=' .$value;
        }
    }

    return $url;
}

private function isUrlContainsRuntimeParameters($url)
{
    preg_match(self::RUNTIME_PARAMETER_PATTERN, $url, $matches);

    return !empty($matches);
}

private function mergeRuntimeParametersValues($parameter)
{
    preg_match(self::RUNTIME_PARAMETER_PATTERN, $parameter, $matches);

    return empty($matches)
        ? $parameter
        : preg_replace(self::RUNTIME_PARAMETER_PATTERN, $this->runtimeParameters[$matches[1]], $parameter);
}
```

I want to rebuild method "iSendARequestTo()" make it works with dynamic Doctrine Values (e.g. uuid)

Comment: I'm not really sure about which question you're asking us. Can you improve it?

Comment: In my Scenario :  
Scenario: User update
    When I send a "PUT" request to "/api/user/f70113bf-dc99"
    Then the response code should be 204  
"f70113bf-dc99" is uuid And it dynamic generated and stored in DB. For now my methods access to work with url: /api/user/10 But I want that it works with dynamic uuid (like /api/user/f70113bf-dc99).

Comment: You need to get this in a previous method/request from DB or somewhere else.